# Interpreting an ODE solution from DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, syntax

I'm doing a project where I need to solve an ODE.

[image: the ode that needs to be solved].

I tried using `DSolve` to solve it, and it gave me an answer, but I'm unsure how to interpret it. The code I'm using is here:

```
epsilon = .5
tau = 1
DSolve[
  y'[t] == (2*Pi*(1 + epsilon*Cos[y[t]])^2)/(tau*(1 - psilon^2)^(3/2)), 
  y[t], t]`
```

It returns an inverse function:

> ```
> {{y[t] -> InverseFunction[1/2 ((4 ArcTan[Tan[#1/2]/Sqrt[3]])/(3 Sqrt[3]) - Sin[#1]/(3 (2 + Cos[#1]))) &][1.2092 t + C[1]]}}
> ```

but also uses `#`, `&`, and `C`, all of which I'm not accustomed to.

Can someone please help me understand what exactly it's showing me?

Comment: Have you read the docs for `DSolve` and `InverseFunction`?  The `C[1]` is an integration constant.  `InverseFunction[f[#]&]` represents the inverse function of `f[y]`.  `y == InverseFunction[f[#]&][t]` if and only if `f[y] == t`. (The `&` represents a way to input a `Function`; the symbol `#` is the argument of the function. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616) for more on strange symbols.)

Answer (score 5):

Let me show, how to get rid of the discontinuities, @Michael E2 observed.

Do separation of variables (y'[t]->dy/dt) of the diffequation and integrate with Rubi https://rulebasedintegration.org/

```
(*   Derivative[1][y][t] == (16 \[Pi] (1 + 1/2 Cos[y[t]])^2)/(3 Sqrt[3])   *)

implsol2[t_, y_] = 
   Int[1/(1 + 1/2 Cos[y])^2, y] == Int[16 Pi/3/Sqrt[3], t] + c2

(*   (8 y)/(3 Sqrt[3]) - (16 ArcTan[Sin[y]/(2 + Sqrt[3] + Cos[y])])/(
     3 Sqrt[3]) - (4 Sin[y])/(3 (2 + Cos[y])) == 
    c2 + (16 \[Pi] t)/(3 Sqrt[3])   *)
```

Solve for y[0]==a

```
sol2 = Solve[implsol2[0, a], c2] // Simplify

(*   {{c2 -> (4 (4 Sqrt[3] a + 2 Sqrt[3] a Cos[a] - 
  4 Sqrt[3] ArcTan[Sin[a]/(2 + Sqrt[3] + Cos[a])] (2 + Cos[a]) - 
  3 Sin[a]))/(9 (2 + Cos[a]))}}   *)

implsol3[t_, y_, a_] = (implsol2[t, y]) /. sol2[[1]]

(*   (8 y)/(3 Sqrt[3]) - (16 ArcTan[Sin[y]/(2 + Sqrt[3] + Cos[y])])/(
3 Sqrt[3]) - (4 Sin[y])/(3 (2 + Cos[y])) == (16 \[Pi] t)/(
3 Sqrt[3]) + (
4 (4 Sqrt[3] a + 2 Sqrt[3] a Cos[a] - 
 4 Sqrt[3] ArcTan[Sin[a]/(2 + Sqrt[3] + Cos[a])] (2 + Cos[a]) - 
 3 Sin[a]))/(9 (2 + Cos[a]))   *)
```

For comparison do numerical integration for a==0

```
epsilon = 1/2;
tau = 1;
yndsol[a_] := 
   y /. First@
   NDSolve[{y'[
   t] == (2 Pi (1 + epsilon*Cos[y[t]])^2)/(tau*(1 - epsilon^2)^(3/
        2)), y[0] == a}, y, {t, 0, 5}]

{ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@Table[implsol3[t , y, a], {a, 0, 4}], {t, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 
30}, PlotPoints -> 50, GridLines -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 200, 
AspectRatio -> 1], 
Plot[Evaluate[yndsol[0][t]], {t, 0, 5}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
ImageSize -> 200, AspectRatio -> 1]}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Nice. :)  A bit tricky (for me) to find a trig identity to get rid of the discontinuity.

Comment: +1 Yours. I let it do Albert Rich.

Answer (score 3):

`#` is just a Placeholder for whatever comes after the `&` symbol. So basically the solution is saying to plug in `1.2092 t + C[1]` into the `#1`.

The `C[1]` is a constant of integration, because you have not specified as initial condition for your ODE. The `1` means that it's a constant, instead than (say) an arbitrary function of $t$. 
 To specify an initial condition, e.g. $ y(t=0.5) = 1.6$, you would write:

```
sol = DSolve[{y'[
     t] == (2*
       Pi*(1 + epsilon*Cos[y[t]])^2)/(tau*(1 - epsilon^2)^(3/2)), 
   y[0.5] == 1.6}, y[t], t]
```

Otherwise, with your solution as is:

```
sol = DSolve[
  y'[t] == (2*
      Pi*(1 + epsilon*Cos[y[t]])^2)/(tau*(1 - epsilon^2)^(3/2)), y[t],
   t]
```

which gives

```
{{y[t] -> 
   InverseFunction[
     1/2 ((4 ArcTan[Tan[#1/2]/Sqrt[3]])/(3 Sqrt[3]) - Sin[#1]/(
         3 (2 + Cos[#1]))) &][1.2092 t + C[1]]}}
```

you can extract it as

```
y[t] /. sol /. C[1] -> 0 /. t -> 0.1 // N
```

which gives `1.59232`.

Answer (score 3):

First, when possible, I use exact coefficients instead of floating-point ones when using exact/symbolic solvers like `DSolve` (`1/2` instead of `0.5`).  It helps avoid problems with round-off error in the solver.

```
epsilon = 1/2;
tau = 1;
dsol = DSolve[
  y'[t] == (2 Pi (1 + epsilon*Cos[y[t]])^2)/(tau*(1 - epsilon^2)^(3/2)),
  y[t], t]
```

You can use the rule `{z_ -> InverseFunction[f_][u_]} :> f[z] == u` to convert a solution in terms of `InverseFunction` to an implicit equation.  Below, I modify this rule to strip the argument from `y[t]`:

```
implsol = dsol /. {y[t] -> InverseFunction[f_][u_]} :> f[y] == u
```

[image]

If you can solve for the integration constant, you can use `ContourPlot` to plot the solution space:

```
First@Values@Solve[implsol, C[1]] // Simplify
ContourPlot[%, {t, 0, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

The translational symmetry is indicative of an autonomous ODE.
The discontinuties are due to `ArcTan[]`; the term `Tan[y/2]` also has a discontinuity. One can transform the equations to get rid of the `ArcTan`, and the solutions align after the transformation:

```
tsol = First@
   Solve[implsol, Cases[implsol, _ArcTan, Infinity, 1]] /.
    {ArcTan[a_] -> b_} :> Sqrt[3] a == Sqrt[3] Tan[b] //
     Simplify;

ContourPlot[
 Evaluate@
  Table[tsol /. C[1] -> k,
   {k, Most@Subdivide[0, (2 Pi)/(3 Sqrt[3]), 5]}],
 {t, 0, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

Here are the actual equations being plotted, with some custom simplification:

```
Table[tsol /. C[1] -> k,
 {k, Most@Subdivide[0, (2 Pi)/(3 Sqrt[3]), 5]}] /.
  {Pi -> pi, Cos[y] -> u - 2} //
    Simplify //
     # /. {pi -> Pi, u -> Cos[y] + 2} &
```

[image]

I cannot think of a way to remove the spurious discontinuities...[*update*] until now:

```
implsolCont = implsol /.
       a_ArcTan :> ArcTan[Tan[a - ArcTan[Tan[y/2]]]] + y/2 /.
      Tan[y/2] -> A/B /.
     Tan[x_] :> TrigExpand@Tan[x] //
    Simplify //
   # /. {A -> Sin[y/2], B -> Cos[y/2]} & //
  FullSimplify[# /. C[1] -> 2 Pi/(3 Sqrt[3]) C[1], 
   ComplexityFunction ->
    (LeafCount[#] + 5 Count[#, _ArcCot, Infinity] &)] &
(*
  {(3 Sin[y])/(2 + Cos[y]) == 
    2 Sqrt[3] (y - 2 ArcTan[Sin[y]/(2 + Sqrt[3] + Cos[y])] - 
       2 Pi (t + C[1]))}
*)
```

Another form of visualization:

```
ty = t /. First@Solve[implsolCont /. C[1] -> 0, t];
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate@Table[{ty + c, y}, {c, -1, 11}],
 {y, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {-10, 10}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `AsymptotcDSolveValue` command may be useful to this end, e.g.

```
tau = 1; epsilon = 1/2;
AsymptoticDSolveValue[ y'[t] == (2* Pi*(1 + epsilon*Cos[y[t]])^2)/
(tau*(1 - epsilon^2)^(3/2)), y[t], {t, 4, 2}]
(*C[1] + 4/9 (-4 + t) (4 Sqrt[3] \[Pi] + 4 Sqrt[3] \[Pi] Cos[C[1]] + 
Sqrt[3] \[Pi] Cos[C[1]]^2) - 16/27 \[Pi]^2 (-4 + t)^2 (2 + Cos[C[1]])^3 Sin[C[1]]*)
```